# App for tracking trips

Tags: mobile-apps, flight-status, flight-data

I'm looking for an app to record my travels. I mainly only want to note flights, with details such as flight number and aircraft. It'd be nice if I got statistics about my travels (such as miles covered) too. App in the Air is what I currently use, and I'm looking for something similar for free or with more features.

Comment: [softwarerecs.se] would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm in love with [FlightDiary](https://my.flightradar24.com/MatteCar).

It belongs to FlightRadar24, you record your flights and it makes statistics.

Comment: This is great! I just set up my profile, and I wish there was an Android and/or WearOS app, but it's perfect otherwise. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep, no app but the mobile GUI is pretty cool!  Just I've been use it for long time and I've never seen any significant improvement (neither before and after Flighradar24 transition), seems like they bought it but they don't have any interest in developing it. Anyway it's already good as it is, hopefully they'll keep it on forever!

Comment: MyFlights seems to be a good mobile alternative if anyone's looking. You can import from FlightDiary, but only half my flights seemed to import properly, and it seems to have some issue with airlines when importing.